# MSBuild : Remove a previously <imported>ed Target dependency

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-target

In my csproj, I am importing a very large heavily used targets file (which I not allowed to break down as of now). This targets file however, sets up various target dependencies / order by using AfterTargets='Build'.

In the csproj where I import this large targets file, I want to remove some of the After build target dependencies. For example, say the following target gets imported:

```
<!-- This is in the large targets file -->
<Target Name="Target1" AfterTargets="Build">
</Target>
```

How do I remove `Target1` from being executed After build in the csproj I am importing it in.
What is a good way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to overwrite the target `Target1` and then set an empty for its target that means you have removed the previous `Target1`.

Although it still appear on the build log, it is empty with no operation. That is the only way. And if you want to make `Target1` not appear, you have to delete it under the large targets file.

You should note that you must write the new `Target1` after the previous one to make the new one overwrite the old one.

For an example,

```
    <!-- This is in the large targets file -->

    <Target Name="Target1" AfterTargets="Build"> // the old one 
    
    //do some larget opertion
    </Target> 
    
    ........
    
    ........
    
    <Target Name="Target1"> // the new one and make it empty
    </Target>
```

Comment: Clarifying two things : 1. The new definition should be in the csproj after the import of the big targets file? and 2. In the new definition, why is the 'AfterTargets="Build"' needed?

Comment: 1) Sure. It should be added after `Target1` to overwrite the old target no matter at the bottom of the targets file or in the csproj file after import node. 2) Sure. You are right. It quite does not need to `AfterTargets="Build"`. I have updated my answer and you can check it.